# InvalidKernelArgs on enqueueNDRange while a similar call works fine

Tags: java, exception, crash, opencl

I'm using JavaCL to process images.
I keep getting

> com.nativelibs4java.opencl.CLException$InvalidKernelArgs: InvalidKernelArgs

On the call to *enqueueNDRange* call in this (part of) function :

```
FloatBuffer outBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4*XYZ.length).order(context.getByteOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
CLFloatBuffer cl_outBuffer = context.createFloatBuffer(CLMem.Usage.Output, outBuffer, false);

CLFloatBuffer cl_inBuffer = context.createFloatBuffer(CLMem.Usage.Input,XYZ.length);
FloatBuffer inBuffer = cl_inBuffer.map(queue, CLMem.MapFlags.Write).put(XYZ);
inBuffer.rewind();
event = cl_inBuffer.unmap(queue, inBuffer);

XYZ2RGBKernel.setArgs(cl_inBuffer, XYZ.length/4,cl_outBuffer);
event = XYZ2RGBKernel.enqueueNDRange(queue, new int[]{XYZ.length/4}, event);

event = cl_outBuffer.read(queue, outBuffer, true, event);
```

XYZ is a pixel array with 4 floats per pixels (encoded like RGBARGBARGBA....)

The associated kernel header is :

```
__kernel void XYZ2RGB(  __constant float3* inputXYZ,
                    int numberOfPixels,
                    __global float* output
                    )
```

I can't figure out why it doesn't work since this call to enqueueNDRange :

```
        CLFloatBuffer cl_Rbuffer = context.createFloatBuffer(CLMem.Usage.Input, R.length);
        FloatBuffer R_buffer = cl_Rbuffer.map(queue, CLMem.MapFlags.Write).put(R);
        R_buffer.rewind();
        event = cl_Rbuffer.unmap(queue, R_buffer);

        CLFloatBuffer cl_Gbuffer = context.createFloatBuffer(CLMem.Usage.Input, G.length);
        FloatBuffer G_buffer = cl_Gbuffer.map(queue, CLMem.MapFlags.Write, event).put(G);
        G_buffer.rewind();
        event = cl_Gbuffer.unmap(queue, G_buffer);

        CLFloatBuffer cl_Bbuffer = context.createFloatBuffer(CLMem.Usage.Input, B.length);
        FloatBuffer B_buffer = cl_Bbuffer.map(queue, CLMem.MapFlags.Write, event).put(B);
        B_buffer.rewind();
        event = cl_Bbuffer.unmap(queue, B_buffer);

        FloatBuffer outBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4*4*R.length).order(context.getByteOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
        CLFloatBuffer cl_outBuffer = context.createFloatBuffer(CLMem.Usage.Output, outBuffer, false);

        RGB2XYZKernel.setArgs(cl_Rbuffer, cl_Gbuffer, cl_Bbuffer, cl_outBuffer);

        event = RGB2XYZKernel.enqueueNDRange(queue, new int[]{R.length}, event);
        event = cl_outBuffer.read(queue, outBuffer, true, event);
```

With the associated kernel header :

```
__kernel void RGB2XYZ(     __constant float* inputR,
                        __constant float* inputG,
                        __constant float* inputB,
                        __global float3* output)
```

Works without any problem.

Before anyone asks, float3 or float4 would work the same, because the OpenCL specs uses 4*sizeof(float) alignment for both. And I've tried switching between the two.
I also tried passing the input as float*, but it doesn't work either.
Both calls happen one after the other.

## Update

I fixed it, after multiple hours :

- __constant seems to have a size limit (couldn't find that in the specs though). XYZ being 4 times the size of R, G or B, it crashed at runtime.
- I had issues afterwards with float3. It seems that the library I'm forced to use isn't up-to-date and so it wasn't supported well enough, so I switched to float4

However if any of you have some more insights about __constant size limit and stuff, let me know, I'm sure it will be handy for the people who will come across this thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> __constant seems to have a size limit (couldn't find that in the specs though).

Limits depend on the device. Constant buffers have a per-buffer size limit (CL_DEVICE_MAX_CONSTANT_BUFFER_SIZE, min 64KB), and there is also a limit on how many constant arguments you can pass to a kernel (CL_DEVICE_MAX_CONSTANT_ARGS, min 8). Both AMD and Nvidia GPUs are usually close to the minimums, so the total amount of data that can be passed as __constant can be very small.

The point of "constant" memory is not to pass read-only input user data to kernels (as you seem to be using it); the point is to store algorithm-specific constants (lookup tables, matrix/polynomial/filter coefficients, etc). If you want to pass read-only input data, the usual way is to declare the kernel argument as `__global const <type>*` and create the corresponding buffer with `CL_MEM_READ_ONLY`.

[Here](https://forums.khronos.org/showthread.php/9192-Const-memory-and-buffer-size-in-openCL) is some more insight.

Comment: Oh thanks for the insights, I'm pretty new to OpenCL. Does the const keyword in OpenCL kernel have the same effect as an argument in a C++ function ? Basically meaning that the function can't change the value/object passed, or is it tied to CL_MEM_READ_ONLY ? Because I have a kernel that can write to a buffer, and then this buffer is used by another kernel as input, making the buffer be a READ_WRITE, so maybe if the const keyword can be used for the second kernel it could be more efficient ?

Comment: Yes, AFAICT it has the same effect as const argument in C/C++. So the compiler will refuse any code that would write into a `global const <type>*` kernel argument. But you can pass a READ_WRITE buffer to such argument. It *could* be more efficient if the compiler can exploit it, but at worst it's going to be the same speed, and may help you avoid some programming errors.